# System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements [MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get a list of products based on the parameters. From a list of product descriptions (Index.chtml), when I click on a product description, I want to go to a page that lists only the products that has that product description.

For ex: If I click on "Barstools" on the Index.chtml page, I want to browse only barstools on the Browse.chtml page.

But I keep on getting this error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Source Error: 

Line 25:         {
Line 26:             // 
Line 27:             var productModel = productDB.ProductDess.Include("Products")
Line 28:                 .Single(p => p.productDesName == productD);
Line 29:             return View(productModel);
```

Here's what I have:

**MODELS:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

---

Product.cs

---

```
[Table("Product")]
[Bind(Exclude = "productID")]
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public string productID { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string productDim { get; set; }
    public string productWoodSp{ get; set; }
    public string productFabric { get; set; }
    public string productTop { get; set; }
    public string productFinish { get; set; }
    public string productAddInfo { get; set; }
    public string productImgURL { get; set; }
    public string productType { get; set; }

    public string collectionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection collection { get; set; }

    public string productDesID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDes ProductDes { get; set; }
}
```

---

ProductDes.cs

---

```
[Table("ProductDes")]
public class ProductDes
{
    [Key]
    public string productDesID { get; set; }
    public string productDesName { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

---

ProductEntities.cs

---

```
public class ProductEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project>    Projects    { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product>    Products    { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductDes> ProductDess  { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLERS::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StoreWeb.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace StoreWeb.Controllers
{
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    ProductEntities productDB = new ProductEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var productDes = productDB.ProductDess.ToList();
        return View(productDes);
    }

    //
    public ActionResult Browse(string productD)
    {
        //
        var productModel = productDB.ProductDess.Include("Products")
            .Single(p => p.productDesName == productD);
        return View(productModel);
    }
}
}
```

**VIEWS:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

```
@model StoreWeb.Models.ProductDes

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse" + Model.productDesName;
}

<h2>Browse</h2>
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {

        <p />
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = product.productID })">
        <img src="@product.productImgURL"  alt="@product.productName" />
            @product.productID @product.productName
        </a> 

    }
```

---

Can someone please advice me what to do? Thank you!

Comment: Problem is EF can not retrieve an entity with the given `productD` value as the `productDesName`. If there is a possibility that record does not exist in the database use 'SingleOrDefault` instead of 'Single`.

Comment: I've tried getting all the products (regardless of their product descriptions) - it worked - it listed all the products in the database. But when I tried to only get products with certain product description, such as "Barstool," it gave me that error..... And I've tried using "SingleOrDefault" as you suggested, then it gave me this error instead:::  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ::: Is there anything else I can try/fix?

Answer (score 5):

In the controller, change

```
var productModel = productDB.ProductDess.Include("Products")
    .Single(p => p.productDesName == productD);
```

to

```
var productModel = productDB.ProductDess.Include("Products")
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.productDesName == productD);
```

In the view, change

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products) {
}
```

to

```
@if (Model != null) {
    foreach (var product in Model.Products) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mikael. With your suggestion, I didn't get any errors, but the page (Browse.chtml) shows up with no results - as if there were no products in the database. But I know they are since I was able to get a list of all products before... Is there another way to get the products based on the parameters?

Comment: Your query does not return anything, that's for sure. Either there are no products in the database or your query is wrong.